# Is there a way to use an if statement before showing the show page?

Tags: admin-on-rest

Is there a way to do an if statement before showing the show page?
For instance if the id of the element I clicked on with the show button end with ".log" I want to have the show page look like this:

```
export const reportShow = ({ ...props }) => (
<Show title="Log" {...props}>
    <SimpleShowLayout>
        <ReferenceManyField label="Log" reference="archivedfiles" target="id">
            <Datagrid>
                <TextField source="id" label="Line" />
                <TextField source="timestamp" label="Timestamp" />
                <TextField source="severity" label="Severity" />
                <TextField source="message" label="Message" />
            </Datagrid>
        </ReferenceManyField>
    </SimpleShowLayout>
</Show>);
```

But if the id ends with .txt I want the show page to show a Report page which would have this:

```
export const reportShow = ({ ...props }) => (
<Show title="Report" {...props}>
    <SimpleShowLayout>
                <TextField source="id" label="Report Name" />
                <TextField source="rmessage" label="Message" />
    </SimpleShowLayout>
</Show>);
```

What would be the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up getting this to work by doing this:

```
export const archivedShow = ({ ...props }) => {
    if (props.match.params.id.endsWith("txt")){
    return (<Show title="Report" {...props}>
        <SimpleShowLayout>
            <ReferenceManyField label="Report" reference="archivedfiles" target="id">
                <Datagrid>
                    <FormattedReportView/>
                </Datagrid>
            </ReferenceManyField>
        </SimpleShowLayout>
    </Show>
    );
    }
    else {
        return (
        <Show title="Log" {...props} filters={< LogFilter/>}>
            <SimpleShowLayout>
            <ReferenceManyField label="Log" reference="archivedfiles" target="id">
                <Datagrid>
                    <TextField source="id" label="Line" />
                    <TextField source="timestamp" label="Timestamp" />
                    <TextField source="severity" label="Severity" />
                    <TextField source="message" label="Message" />
                </Datagrid>
            </ReferenceManyField>
        </SimpleShowLayout>
        </Show>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the [aor-dependent-input](https://github.com/marmelab/aor-dependent-input) addon can help you with that.

Comment: If i were to use DependentInput how would I say
if( id ends with .txt) {...
}
?

Comment: I forgot this addon was designed for inputs and not fields. I'll see what we can do about that

Comment: FYI, I just released a new version of the [aor-dependent-input](https://github.com/marmelab/aor-dependent-input) addon which now provides an `DependentField` component for views. Use it with the `resolve` prop to check constraints in the `id` field

Comment: Do you have an example on how to use DependentField? The link you gave seems to only have DependentInput examples. @Gildas

Comment: Both components have the exact same props and can be used the same way